# Selection sort to merge sort

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort, selection-sort

Below I have provided my example of selection sort code, which if possible I want to convert to merge sort (I am using a linked-list as my data type):

```
public void sortRawDataRepository() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rawDataRepository.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < rawDataRepository.size(); j++) {
            Date iDate = rawDataRepository.get(i).getProductionDate();
            Date jDate = rawDataRepository.get(j).getProductionDate();
            if (iDate.getTime() > jDate.getTime()) {
                Item tmp = rawDataRepository.get(i);
                rawDataRepository.set(i, rawDataRepository.get(j));
                rawDataRepository.set(j, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) the core ideas of selection sort and merge sort are totally different. Why do you want to transform the code instead of rewriting it from scratch? b) Why do you not implement a `Comparator` or write one as lambda-function and use `Collections.sort(...)` (`rawDataRepository` seems to be some kind of `Collection`)?

Comment: I wanted to try something different and want to implement by own sorting algorithms instead of using in-built sort.

Comment: In this case I would suggest you start by sorting an array. Internally, `Collections.sort(...)` uses `Arrays.sort(...)` as well, so you have a good motivation to sort arrays instead of `Collection`s/`List`s.

Comment: Sorry, I think you didn't quite get what I was meaning to say. I want to implement my own sorting algorithms instead of using built in method provided by java.

Comment: You should edit your question to tell us what exactly is stopping you from doing that. There are resources for sorting algorithms all over the internet.

Comment: Don't exactly understand what you mean by transform. as @Turing85 said they are totally different!

Comment: @MeroRai I understand you perfectly well. But I wanted to give you a motivation to implement your sorting algorithm for arrays instead for `Collection`s, since it is not possible to implement merge sort for `Collection`s (efficiently), because you cannot (efficiently) split a `Collection` into two parts (which is what you need for e.g. merge sort).